# how to update a column with same sequence

Tags: sql, t-sql

i need to update a table with another column (userID ) to Lastname Column .So i have written query like this

```
update User set LastName = +'LastName_'+ CONVERT (varchar(10),UserID)
```

and result giving like this

```
UserID    FirstName             LastName  
1               AALIYAH             Bhatt_1
2               Mohan               Kumar_2
3               varun               ratna_3
4               suresh              rania_4
5               AARON               suresh_5    

etc ......

4500            Kalyan              raju_4500
4501            raohan              manish4501
```

and how can i get last name in the sequence..
see the last column for example 4500 so last name is updated as raju_4500 and coming to first name userId(1) and lastname is Bhatt_1

how could i get in sequence

```
UserID    FirstName             LastName  
1               AALIYAH             Bhatt_0001
2               Mohan               Kumar_0002
3               varun               ratna_0003
4               suresh              rania_0004
5               AARON               suresh_0005 

etc ......

4500            Kalyan              raju_4500
4501            raohan              manish4501
```

Suggest me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression gives you the length of the maximum UserID:

```
select len(max(userid)) from User
```

And you can put leading zeros on a number like this:

```
select right('0000000000' + convert(varchar(10), /*number*/), /*length*/)
```

So, putting that together, I would do this:

```
declare @length int = (select len(max(userid)) from User)
update User set LastName = 'LastName_' + 
    right('0000000000' + convert(varchar(10), UserID), @length)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
update User set LastName = +'LastName_'+  RIGHT('0000'+ CONVERT(varchar(10),UserID),4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give the exact result.

```
update User set LastName = LastName +'_'+RIGHT('000'+cast(UserID as varchar), 4)
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8d1f2/1)**

Answer (score 0):

try out this

```
update User set LastName = +'LastName_'+  RIGHT('0000'+ CONVERT(varchar(10),UserID),4)
```